# Sum lines below each line in a file linux

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have input like this

```
A  100
B  150
C  200
D  250
E  300
```

THe output i want is the sum of of all the elements above that: Something like this

```
   A to A - 100
   A to B - 250
   A to C - 450
   A to D - 700
   A to E - 1000
   B to B - 150
   B to C - 350
   B to D - 600
   B to E - 900
   C to C - 200
   C to D - 450
   C to E - 650
   D to D - 250
   D to E - 550
   E to E - 300
```

The file size is around 250 MB. I wrote a python program which stores everyline in a dictionary first. But i think it is not feasible for large inputs. I am a beginner using linux.

Comment: I don't think [tag:linux] is a relevant tag.

Comment: Is there always only one line per "element"? Or can there be more?

Comment: Can you show us what you've attempted so far?

Comment: @EtanReisner
There is only one line per element

Comment: @HuuNguyen As i mentioned, I wrote a python program to do that for smaller files. But i dont think its feasible for bigger files

Comment: It might be helpful to post relevant parts of that program so that we can determine together whether it's reasonable to use for larger files.

Comment: I am posting this from a mobile...Will post once i get access to my laptop

Comment: If you need every pair of values output like that (whatever the formatting of the lines is exactly) then I don't know that you can do better than storing `N - 1` values for each element and updating them all for each new value you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of storing the values and a nested loop:

```
awk '
    { label[NR]=$1; val[NR]=$2 } 
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
            sum = 0
            for (j=i; j<=NR; j++) {
                sum += val[j]
                print label[i] " to " label[j] " - " sum
            }
        }
    }
' file
```

I think this will still be slow for large files (you have to store the whole file in memory, and it's an O(N^2) (or is it O(NlogN), it's been a while...) operation to do the nested loop. I suspect throwing the data in a database would help you out.

Answer (score 1):

So your input file is around 250MB, you say. Let's call it exactly 250MB, or 262144000 bytes. Your representative inputs are 7 bytes per line - a single character, two spaces, a three digit number, and a  newline. That means something on the order of 37449142 individual lines.

If your intention is to ultimately generate an output for every possible pair of lines within the input file, as it seems to be, then you need to be prepared to store 37449142 * 37449143 / 2 = 701219136992653 separate lines of output. At the representative 7 bytes each, and ignoring the fact that the majority of them will probably end up even larger, that's 4908533958948571 bytes, or 4464 terabytes of data you'll need to store.

Hope your budget has enough funding for a few large EMC arrays. Otherwise, as you suspect, this just might be a little on the not feasible side...

Comment: 4464TB...?? :o definitely not an option

Answer (score 0):

using python:

```
>>> value =[]
>>> name = []
>>> f=open('yourfile.txt')
>>> for x in f:
...     x=x.strip()
...     na,va = x.split()
...     name.append(na)
...     value.append(va)
... 
>>> name
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
>>> value
['100', '150', '200', '250', '300']
>>> for i in range(len(name)):
...     for j in range(i,len(name)):
...         print name[i],name[j],str(sum(map(int,value[i:j+1])))
...
```

output:

```
A A 100
A B 250
A C 450
A D 700
A E 1000
B B 150
B C 350
B D 600
B E 900
C C 200
C D 450
C E 750
D D 250
D E 550
E E 300
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can do this using [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) and [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). The only thing stored in memory here is a dictionary with items from first column as key and items from second column as value:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = OrderedDict((k, int(v)) for k, v in (line.split() for line in f))
    start = None
    tot = 0
    for k1, k2 in combinations_with_replacement(data.iterkeys(), 2):
        if k1 != start:
            start = k1
            tot = data[k1]
            print '{} to {} - {}'.format(k1, k2, tot)
        else:
            tot += data[k2]
            print '{} to {} - {}'.format(k1, k2, tot)
```

**Output:**

```
A to A - 100
A to B - 250
A to C - 450
A to D - 700
A to E - 1000
B to B - 150
B to C - 350
B to D - 600
B to E - 900
C to C - 200
C to D - 450
C to E - 750
D to D - 250
D to E - 550
E to E - 300
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick one:

```
awk '{s+=$2; printf("%s - %d\n", $1, s)}' <your-file>
```

If you want to print `A to A, A to B` etc, we will have to get more fancy:

(in tcsh)

```
foreach n (`seq 5 -1 1`)
tail -$n <your-file> | awk '{s+=$2; if (a) NR; else{ a=$1;} printf("%s to %s - %d\n", a, $1, s);}'
end
```

Sample output:

```
A - 100
B - 250
C - 450
D - 700
E - 1000
B to B - 150
B to C - 350
B to D - 600
B to E - 900
C to C - 200
C to D - 450
C to E - 750
D to D - 250
D to E - 550
E to E - 300
```

Comment: Nope. Formatting doesnt matter.

Comment: @sparshithp Do you mean you don't need the `X to Y` output for each pair? If not what pairs/ranges *do* you need?

Comment: Might be better to save `$1` on the first line and print `printf "%s to %s - %d\n", first, $1, s` just to be clear.

Comment: @EtanReisner 
I need X to Y. I meant i dont need the exact format X to Y..it can be X,Y or X Y.. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @sparshithp, I misread the problem - didn't see that you wanted the rows to continue B to B...

Comment: @sparshithp - added some more code to actually solve the problem.